# Xpages set datasource property

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'd like to have certain data sources on my page with the property loaded="false" and then using onClick for example set it to true.  I hear about people doing this but I cannot seem to find and example with SSJS?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a session scoped variable to toggle the loading of the data source. onclick, change the value of this.

Since you're using the loaded property, I believe you have to do reopen the page (it's not enough with full refresh). E.g. by redirect.

Comment: You can make a *context.reloadPage()* in your SSJS action. This will "recalculate" the datasources too.